# How to make timestamp minutes 00 in mysql

Tags: mysql

Actually I want to replace timestamp minutes into 00 for all selected date from my table like below,

2016-03-28 04:58:37

2016-03-28 05:58:33

2016-03-28 06:24:18

into

2016-03-28 04:00:37

2016-03-28 05:00:37

2016-03-28 06:00:18

I must do this in select query only. anybody have idea for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
YourColumnHere - second(YourColumnHere);
```

Or this:

```
date_format(YourColumnHere, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:%S');
```

Or this:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(((TIME_TO_SEC(YourColumnHere)+30) DIV 60) * 60
```

Comment: sorry i want to make 2016-03-28 05:58:33 into 2016-03-28 05:00:33

Comment: Try the first one and replace second with minute @mmmms

Comment: Try my second query now @mmmms